# Bytes object has not attribute json with requests

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am extracting `BTC` history data from a website and want to store these results. I want to run this in a function and then use `map` because it's much faster than storing everything within a dict by using a loop. However, I get the following error:

```
      1 def storeBitcoin(response):
      2     bitcoin = defaultdict(list)
----> 3     for row in range(0, len(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'])):
      4         bitcoin['timestamp'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['T'])
      5         bitcoin['open'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['O'])

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'json'
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
params = {
        'token': 'jTf9y32fLnC5GG64AIQNFZzlCiS73L7L',
        'codeid': '3223607',
        'interval': '35',
        'from': '1651751935',
        'to': '1651838395',
    }
    
response = requests.get('https://www.btcc.com/quot/history', params=params)


def storeBitcoin(response):
    bitcoin = defaultdict(list)
    for row in range(0, len(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'])):
        bitcoin['timestamp'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['T'])
        bitcoin['open'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['O'])
        bitcoin['closed'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['C'])
        bitcoin['high'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['H'])
        bitcoin['low'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['L'])
    return bitcoin

list(map(storeBitcoin, response)) #error starts here
```

I have tested my function by using the loop inside and storing it in a dict with the results from requests and it does work. Why am I getting the error?

working code:

```
params = {
        'token': 'jTf9y32fLnC5GG64AIQNFZzlCiS73L7L',
        'codeid': '3223607',
        'interval': '35',
        'from': '1651751935',
        'to': '1651838395',
    }
    
response = requests.get('https://www.btcc.com/quot/history', params=params)

bitcoin = defaultdict(list)
for row in range(0, len(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'])):
    bitcoin['timestamp'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['T'])
    bitcoin['open'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['O'])
    bitcoin['closed'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['C'])
    bitcoin['high'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['H'])
    bitcoin['low'].append(response.json()['data']['KdataInfo'][row]['L'])
```

Managed to get it to work with the following thanks to Scott's comments:

```
i = 0
#bitcoin = defaultdict(list)
full_response = []
while i < 8:
    i+=1
    val_begin = np.array([1651751935])
    val_end = np.array([1651838395])
    np.add.at(val_begin, [0], i)
    np.add.at(val_end, [0], i)
    
    params = {
        'token': 'jTf9y32fLnC5GG64AIQNFZzlCiS73L7L',
        'codeid': '3223607',
        'interval': '35',
        'from': str(val_begin[0]),
        'to': str(val_end[0]),
    }
    
    response = requests.get('https://www.btcc.com/quot/history', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
    full_response.append(response)

list(map(storeBitcoin, full_response))
```

Comment: Please show the full error trace, and the actual code you used that "worked".

Comment: @ScottHunter Updated with full error trace and code that worked

Comment: Why do you think `map(storeBitcoin, response)` does?  Why would you expect it to work if `stroeBitcoin(response)` (which is effectively what your working code does) works?

Comment: @ScottHunter it should map the function onto each element in the list, so if response is saved as a list then it should perform the function on every element in the list.

Comment: But your code that works uses `response` as is, and not each element within it individually, which is what `map` tries to do.

Comment: @ScottHunter I was meant to have multiple of these but I have figured it out with your comment, and I have added it to the post.

Comment: As an aside, you can greatly simplify the code (and almost certainly improve performance) by using a local variable to remember the value of `response.json()['data']['KdataInfo']`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That is my aim, to try and improve the performance, I will give that a go- thanks